# DataContract composite Class

Tags: wcf, datacontract, datamember

I have a problem with serialization composite class (using WCF Service).

here my class in namespace1 (it is not in service namespace) :

```
 [DataContract]
    public class UpData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public double Version ;

        public UpData()
        {
            this.Version = -1;    
        }
    }
```

In my Service namespace (in interface) I deсlare this procedure :

```
ArrayList GetDownloadPath(Dictionary<string,string> lib1, Dictionary<string,string> lib2);
```

ArrayList contains UpData objects.

I have error(

How will be right to send ArrayList of UpData objects? (may be specific DataContract?)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please post your error message? Are you getting a SerializationException?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `ArrayList` is serializable by default. Using a generic list could solve your problem:

```
[OperationContract]
List<UpData> GetDownloadPath(Dictionary<string,string> lib1, Dictionary<string,string> lib2);
```

**EDIT:** I think you also need to specify a getter and setter for your `Version` property, i.e.

```
[DataContract]
public class UpData
{
    [DataMember]
    public double Version { get; set; }

    public UpData()
    {
        this.Version = -1;    
    }
}
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, it is not work( The mistake is in declare class UpData. I think)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it is not work : the app.config file (on client app) does not fill. (<bindings> and <client>).

Comment: If I use class UpData2 (analog UpData, but another name), which declare in service namespace - it works normal.